# Writing content stored in variable to csv file

Tags: php, csv, file-put-contents

I have a line of data stored in `$StripContent`, when I echo `$Stripcontent` it shows

> , , ,1 ,1415 ,Fietsen ,Omafietsen ,Avalon ,F 101 Oma Export 57cm Zwart , ,57 ,single speed remnaaf ,2017 ,21 ,249.00 ,135.00 ,19.50 ,8

However when I write `$Stripcontent` to the CSV file it only writes the first character instead of the whole line.

```
$Get_Content = file_get_contents($newname);

$StripContent = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",',', $Get_Content);

$file = $newname;
$content = file($file); 
foreach($content as $lineNumber => &$lineContent) { 
    if($lineNumber == 0) {
        $lineContent .= $StripContent . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}

$allContent = implode("", $content); 
file_put_contents($file, $allContent);
```

Comment: Did you tried anything more? It's working now?

Comment: It is working now, I do however, have another problem if you would be so kind to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411466/select-specific-lines-and-replace-them-using-php?

Comment: If its working and solved, mark as solved (this way the SO platforms keeps clean & updated). If the answer helps you, upvote ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it more direct with the `$Stripcontent` variable direclty, whithout the `foreach` part, like:

```
$Get_Content = file_get_contents($newname);

$StripContent = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",',', $Get_Content);

$file = $newname;
$content = file($file); 
file_put_contents($file, $Stripcontent);
```

This works if you want to store the `stripContent` string. I recomend you to wrap it between a `try{...}catch()` and check for folder permisions to avoid problems!

Or if you want to use the built-in function for CSV you can use `fputcsv` ([offical documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)):

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Hope it helps!